# Full screen app in a small window (Picture in picture)

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I'm currently running Mac OS X 10.10.1. Is there a way to get a full screen app into a window?

Example:

I have netflix running in a web browser full screen on one desktop. I'd like to take that full screen window and do a "picture in picture" and show it in the corner of the current desktop I'm working on. Is there an app out there that does this, or can it be done natively?

Alternatively, I realize that I can resize the window myself but I still have to deal with unused real estate (e.g. borders), and battling with making sure its always in focus.

Answer (score 1):

FullScreen & windowed are really mutually exclusive.

If you run windowed, there's the possibility that [Afloat](http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/master-windows-afloat-mac) might work for you, to keep it always in front; unfortunately it is no longer supported & I don't know whether it still works in Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

The closest one would get to what you want is using the VLC player.

In VLC you would use the File "open network" and enter the URL for the Netflix file.

Then in Video menu bar tab select the "float on top" to have the window always on top (in focus).

Now resize it to your liking and move it to your liking.

It is not a full screen, since it will still have windows border ect. but as said it is closest to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works for you:

1. Open up Automator and create a new "App" document.
2. add the "Get current Webpage from Safari" (or "Get specified URLs") action
3. add the "Website Popup" action as a next step 
   and configure both website size (e.g. iPhone) 
   and user agent (iPhone optimised websites are easier to navigate in this size)
4. Save your application wherever you want and use it ;-)